# Problem using jest with storybook snapshot testing in react native

Tags: react-native, jestjs, storybook

### What I have

I'm trying to use jest and Storybook with Storyshots addon for snapshot test in my react-native/typescript app, but I'm having some issues when I try to run simple test.

According to Snapshot testing section in [storybook documentation](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/simple-component/), the only thing you need to do is create an `storybook.test.js` file with the following:

#### storybook.test.js

```js
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';
initStoryshots();
```

After this, everything is supposed to work as expected, but the console throws the following error:

```sh
● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to
 import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g.
it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config,
it will use that to transform your files, ign
oring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Mo
dules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascri
pt-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" fi
les transformed, you can specify a custom "tr
ansformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation sp
ecify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS
 modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub th
em out with the "moduleNameMapper" config opt
ion.

    You'll find more details and examples of
these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.h
tml

    Details:

    C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\myapp\node_m
odules\react-native-swipe-gestures\index.js:3
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement
outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_m
odules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@st
orybook/react-native/dist/preview/components/
OnDeviceUI/navigation/index.js:29:53)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.468 s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

#### jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node']
};
```

#### babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset']
};
```

If I remove `@storybook/addon-storyshots` relate things from my tests, everything is working normally without any problem. So **I don't know if I need some extra configuration to make work storybook/jest snapshoot testing with react native.**

Comment: Any chance you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your storybook directory in the **configPath** in your **initStoryshots** call in the test file like this:

```
import path from 'path'
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots'

initStoryshots({
  framework: 'react-native',
  configPath: path.join(__dirname, '/path_to_your_storybook'),
})
```

And update your **jest.config.js** by adding the **transformIgnorePatterns** to ignore the node modules add on files as follows

```
module.exports = {
  ...your config,
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
     "node_modules/(?!@storybook|((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)",
     "\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$",
     "node_modules/@storybook/addon-storyshots/dist/ts3.9/frameworks/preact/*"
  ]
};
```

The important point here is to require the storybooks files this will allow **storyshots** to actually find your stories to execute snap shot test.

Answer (score -2):

It's enough. Add `react-native-swipe-gestures` to `transformIgnorePatterns` of your `jest.config.js`.

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(react-native|@react-navigation|@react-native|react-native-swipe-gestures)/)'],
```

This did a trick for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).